# How to create a Time Bar in LibGDX?

Tags: java, timer, libgdx, progress-bar

I am programming a game, and wanted to add a time bar (a bar that decreases over time).
The game is basically, some enemies come from one side and you have to punch them. So when you punch one the time bar has to increase a little bit. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: what have you already done? usually its wise to write your own components

Comment: I haven't written anything regarding the time bar

Comment: and what are u expecting from us now? since no code or explicit question is provided i assume you want an approach. So my suggestion would be : write your components (e.g. extend Stack) and override the render method or just use a progressbar

Comment: I was hoping that someone could put me in the right direction with an example or something. I tried with the progressbar but it behaves differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just put some code from my small framework ,the code will not work alone and you have to do some changes but at least will put you in your way.

```
public class ProgressBar extends UIitem {

    public Sprite sprite,sprite2;
    public boolean visible=true;


    //texture is the progress bar (the one that decreases and background is the background texture of the progress bar
    public ProgressBar(float x, float y, float sizex, float sizey, Texture texture,Texture background) {
        pos = new Vector(x, y);
        size = new Vector(sizex, sizey);
        sprite = new Sprite(texture);
        sprite2 = new Sprite(background);
        color = new gColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    }

    float timeon=0;

    float progress,orogressMb;
    public float getProgress() {
        return orogressMb;
    }
    public void setProgress(float p){
        orogressMb=p;
        if(orogressMb>1)orogressMb=1;
        else if(orogressMb<0)orogressMb=0;
    }

    @Override
    public void Render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        if(!visible)return;

        sprite2.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a);
        sprite2.setRotation(0);
        sprite2.setPosition(getPos().x - getSize().x * scaleup / 2, getPos().y- getSize().y * scaleup / 2);
        sprite2.setSize(getSize().x * scaleup, getSize().y * scaleup);
        sprite2.setOrigin((getSize().x * scaleup) / 2,(getSize().y * scaleup) / 2);
        sprite2.draw(sb);

        sprite.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a);
        sprite.setRotation(0);
        sprite.setRegion(0, 0, progress, 1);
        sprite.setSize((getSize().x * scaleup)*progress, getSize().y * scaleup);
        sprite.setPosition(getPos().x-getSize().x/2, getPos().y- getSize().y * scaleup / 2);
        sprite.setOrigin((getSize().x * scaleup) / 2,(getSize().y * scaleup) / 2);
        sprite.draw(sb);

        timeon+=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(timeon>0.5f){
            progress+=((orogressMb-progress)/10)*Director.delta;
        }
    }

}
```